# Oracle sql, using of relational view

Tags: sql, oracle

i have create a table TRKTRIPLEG(as below):

```
CREATE TABLE TRKTRIPLEG(
        T#              NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL,
        LEG#            NUMBER(2)       NOT NULL,
        DEPARTURE       VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
        DESTINATION     VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT TRKTRIPLEG_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (T#, LEG#),
        CONSTRAINT TRKTRIPLEG_UNIQUE UNIQUE(T#, DEPARTURE, DESTINATION),
        CONSTRAINT TRKTRIPLEG_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY (T#) REFERENCES TRKTRIP(T#) );
```

and I have inserted some values into the table:

```
INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES(10, 1, 'Perth', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES(10, 2, 'Sydney', 'Brisbane');
```

The output that I suppose to come out with should be something like this:

```
T# ORIGIN DESTINATION1 DESTINATION2
---- ---------- ------------------- ----------------
10 Perth   Sydney       Brisbane
```

I have stuck on this for quite some time and can't seems to get it right.... any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.t#, 
       o.departure,
       o.destination as destination_1,
       d.destination as destionation_2
from tripleg o
  join tripleg d on o.t# = d.t# and o.departure = d.origin
```

Comment: thanks! it's getting close to what i want.... however when i insert new value "INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES(11, 1, 'Sydney', 'Melbourne');" the query does not output the new data.. why is that so? i have tried using left outer join.. but still it doesn;t work.

Comment: @wjs, because the new row has different value for the `T#` column. So it does not "belong" to the already existing value 10.